# is it possible to select a range in Excel using VBA and put a value like text or some formulas?

Tags: excel, vba

i just want to ask if it is possible to select a value in excel and put some text or formula?

Thank you in advance guys.

Comment: The quick answer is, "yes it is possible".  But we would need a lot more information to help, like any code you have tried.  Stack Overflow is not here to teach you how to code nor to code for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not even sure I understand what you're asking.

*select a value in excel and put some text or formula*

So you want to search for something than replace that with something else? (text/formula).

Or just if it's possible to change a Cells value?

Start with the easier, change a Cells value or add a formula

```
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

'Set A1's Value to 12
ws.Cells("A1").Value = "12"

'Insert formula to show today's date
ws.Cells("A2").Formula = "=TEXT(NOW(),""yyyy.mm.dd"")"
```

For the other possibility

Copied from MSDN's [Range.FindNext Method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196143.aspx)

```
With Worksheets(1).Range("a1:a500") 
    Set c = .Find(2, lookin:=xlValues) 
    If Not c Is Nothing Then 
        firstAddress = c.Address 
        Do 
            c.Value = 5 
            Set c = .FindNext(c) 
        Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress 
    End If 
End With
```

Changes every 2 to 5 within the Range A1:A500

*(Why did I even wrote this?)*

Comment: I got it, this is what i mean, anyway sorry for the lack of information. thanks a lot.